# Perform groupby one hot encoding in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a data frame as shown below

## df:

```
cust_id         product
1               tv
1               phone
2               bat
2               ball
3               bat
4               ball
4               bat
4               tv
4               phone
5               tv
6               bat
7               bat
7               ball
7               tv
7               phone
8               phone
8               tv
```

from the above I would like to prepare below which basically perform groupby `cust_id` and one hot encoding on the column `product`.

Expected output:

```
product       ball      bat       phone     tv
cust_id      
1             0         0         1         1
2             1         1         0         0
3             0         1         0         0
4             1         1         1         1
5             0         0         0         1
6             0         1         0         0
7             1         1         1         1
8             0         0         1         1
```

I have tried following code but that did not work.

## try-1:

```
one_hot = pd.get_dummies(df.groupby('cust_id')['product'])
one_hot
```

## try-2

```
df.pivot_table(index=['cust_id'], 
                      columns='product', 
                      values='product')
```

## try-3

```
df1 = (df.sort_values(['cust_id', 'product'])
         .groupby('cust_id')['product'].agg(list)
         .reset_index(name='product_list')
      )

df1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `hot encoding` alwayes return `0,1` as necessary aggregate `max`:

```
one_hot = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('cust_id')['product']).groupby(level=0).max()
```

And if count values per columns need `clip` for maximal `1` value:

```
one_hot = pd.crosstab(df["cust_id"], df["product"]).clip(upper=1)
```

Sample:

```
print (df)
    cust_id product
0         1    ball
1         1    ball
2         1    ball
3         1   phone
4         2     bat
5         2    ball
6         3     bat
7         4    ball
8         4     bat
9         4     bat
10        4      tv
11        4   phone
```

---

```
one_hot = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('cust_id')['product']).groupby(level=0).max()
print (one_hot)
         ball  bat  phone  tv
cust_id                      
1           1    0      1   0
2           1    1      0   0
3           0    1      0   0
4           1    1      1   1
```

---

```
#count values - possible another integers like 0,1
print (pd.crosstab(df["cust_id"], df["product"]))
product  ball  bat  phone  tv
cust_id                      
1           3    0      1   0
2           1    1      0   0
3           0    1      0   0
4           1    2      1   1

one_hot = pd.crosstab(df["cust_id"], df["product"]).clip(upper=1)
print (one_hot)
product  ball  bat  phone  tv
cust_id                      
1           1    0      1   0
2           1    1      0   0
3           0    1      0   0
4           1    1      1   1
```

Answer (score 2):

[`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
pd.crosstab(df['cust_id'],df['product'])

product  ball  bat  phone  tv
cust_id                      
1           0    0      1   1
2           1    1      0   0
3           0    1      0   0
4           1    1      1   1
5           0    0      0   1
6           0    1      0   0
7           1    1      1   1
8           0    0      1   1
```

Comment: This is not `hot-encoding`, check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
x = pd.crosstab(df["cust_id"], df["product"])
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
product  ball  bat  phone  tv
cust_id                      
1           0    0      1   1
2           1    1      0   0
3           0    1      0   0
4           1    1      1   1
5           0    0      0   1
6           0    1      0   0
7           1    1      1   1
8           0    0      1   1
```